# How do i update a apt package on github

Tags: github, sfml, apt, github-ci

I have some code on github, and it needs sfml 2.5.1, and i have a github ci set up to compile my code. However, when installing sfml, it installs 2.4.2. I have tried to do `sudo apt update`, but that doesn't seem to work (cmake says sfml is version 2.4.2)

Comment: It appears that the latest release of sfml is 2.5.1.  I'm not sure where you're getting that version number from.

Comment: cmake PkgConfig

Comment: @bk2204 im stupid, had a typo. I meant 2.5.1